# Hunter doesn't see the cpp redis library

Tags: c++

I want use cpp-redis, create some simple project and hunter doesn't see cpp-redis when I try to build this:

cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

include("cmake/HunterGate.cmake")
HunterGate(
    URL "https://github.com/cpp-pm/hunter/archive/v0.24.2.tar.gz"
    SHA1 "17fd3b9f0b8c271eac9b71e30a6aa1b9fecab299"
)

project(MyProject)

hunter_add_package(cpp_redis)
find_package(cpp_redis CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(MyApp main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MyApp PRIVATE cpp_redis::cpp_redis)
```

I do some simple main file for test, main.cpp:

```
#include <cpp_redis/cpp_redis>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
cpp_redis::client client;
client.connect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
client.set("hello", "world", [](cpp_redis::reply &reply) {
   std::cout << "SET hello world: " << reply << std::endl;
});
client.sync_commit();
return 0;
}
```

The error does not seem to swear at the inclusion, but swears at the code itself, supposedly there is no such thing, although this is an example from the official repository:

```
test_redis/build$ make
[ 50%] Building CXX object MyApp.dir/main.cpp.o
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:16: error: ‘client’ is not a member of ‘cpp_redis’
    5 |     cpp_redis::client client;
      |                ^~~~~~
main.cpp:6:5: error: ‘client’ was not declared in this scope
    6 |     client.connect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
      |     ^~~~~~
```

I trying different ways for building my app, some private or public link libs, try include directories redis, check paths which use cmake